# Starting a jar with double click starts in 32bit JVM, but from console in 64bit JVM

Tags: java, jar, console, 32bit-64bit, double-click

Since I'm using native libraries I have different JARs for 32bit and 64bit platforms.
Now when there are two JVMs installed on the system, one 32bit and one 64bit I face this behaviour:

**Double clicking the 32bit JAR** -> works

**Double clicking the 64bit JAR** -> App doesn't start

**Starting the 32bit JAR from console** -> Error: This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM.Please install the desired version.

**Starting the 64bit JAR from console** -> works

On Mac I can start the 32bit JAR from console, when adding -d32 to the command. But on Windows, this doesn't work.

I expect, that on a system, where a 64bit JVM is installed, the JAR should start in 64bit JVM, no matter if started by double click or via console.

I there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: It seems that: a) you have path to the 64 bit java in your `PATH` env var; b) the default program associated with the `.jar` extension is the 32 bit version.

Comment: What's your Windows version, and what's the jar you are trying to open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check where the `PATH` environment variable points to. I think you will find that it points to your 64-bit JVM, as opposed to the default application associated with `.jar` files, which will probably be a 32-bit JVM on your system. Align those two values, and you should be fine.