# MS Access DB ODBC Driver Mgr issue

Tags: java, database, odbc, driver, ms-access-2010

I am working on an Java application which connects to Access DB and I am able to connect to the Access db on eclipse when running locally.

But when I export the jar of the project and run the executable jar on my local machine(before I deploy it to prod I find this error). I dont see how it worked before and doesnt work afterwards.

```
public boolean openConnection() {
        boolean rtn = false;
        try {
            String myDB = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" + 
                    "DBQ=" + this.pathToDatabase + ";UID=" + this.username + 
                    ";PWD="+ this.password + ";";
            logger.debug("Connecting to database using: " + myDB);
            this.dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(myDB, "", "");
            rtn = true;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            printSQLException(ex);
        }
        return rtn;
    }
```

Exception:

```
2013-12-04 18:26:55,270 [main] WARN GenericDatabaseWrapper - SQLState: IM002
2013-12-04 18:26:55,338 [main] WARN  GenericDatabaseWrapper - Error Code: 0
2013-12-04 18:26:55,366 [main] WARN  GenericDatabaseWrapper - Message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

Comment: Have your app show you `System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")` when it starts up. Do you see the same value when you run it in Eclipse vs. when you run the executable .jar file?

Comment: thanks Gord for replying.. Its printing.. 64 when I run on executable .jar file and 32 when i run from eclipse

Comment: Tried to set the value using System.setProperty("sun.arch.data.model",32) but still it doesnt work on executable jar

Comment: Check out the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14875368/2144390) and see if it helps.